# SQL optimization question (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

Edit:  Please answer one of the two answers I ask.  I *know* there are other options that would be better in a different case.  These other potential options (partitioning the table, running as one large delete statement w/o committing in batches, etc) are **NOT** options in my case due to things outside my control.

I have several very large tables to delete from.  All have the same foreign key that is indexed.  I need to delete certain records from all tables.

```
table source
  id --primary_key
  import_source --used for choosing the ids to delete

table t1
  id --foreign key
  --other fields

table t2
  id --foreign key
  --different other fields
```

Usually when doing a delete like this, I'll put together a loop to step through all the ids:

```
declare
my_counter integer := 0;
begin
for cur in (
select id from source where import_source = 'bad.txt'
) loop
  begin
    delete from source where id = cur.id;
    delete from t1 where id = cur.id;
    delete from t2 where id = cur.id;
    my_counter := my_counter + 1;
    if my_counter > 500 then
      my_counter := 0;
      commit;
    end if;
    end;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
```

However, in some code I saw elsewhere, it was put together in separate loops, one for each delete.

```
declare
type import_ids is table of integer index by pls_integer;
my_count integer := 0;
begin
select id bulk collect into my_import_ids from source where import_source = 'bad.txt'

for h in 1..my_import_ids.count
  delete from t1 where id = my_import_ids(h);
    --do commit check
end loop;
for h in 1..my_import_ids.count
  delete from t2 where id = my_import_ids(h);
    --do commit check
end loop;

--do commit check will be replaced with the same chunk to commit every 500 rows as the above query
```

So I need one of the following answered:

1) Which of these is better?

2) How can I find out which is better for my particular case? (IE if it depends on how many tables I have, how big they are, etc)

Edit:

I *must* do this in a loop due to the size of these tables.  I will be deleting thousands of records from tables with hundreds of millions of records.  This is happening on a system that can't afford to have the tables locked for that long.

EDIT:

NOTE:  I am *required* to commit in batches.  The amount of data is too large to do it in one batch.  The rollback tables will crash our database.

If there is a way to commit in batches other than looping, I'd be willing to hear it.  Otherwise, don't bother saying that I shouldn't use a loop...

Comment: If you feel you that you have to resort to loops because of the tables' large size, have you (and/or DBA) looked at using the database engine's partitioning functionality?  That's one of the "use cases" that partitioning helps with.  For example, if you have a 10 terabyte table with a billion rows, it's easier to delete a partition (based on ID) than to iterate over millions of rows.

Comment: Yes, we have considered this.  We have partitioned pieces of our database.  However, the t1 and t2 (etc) tables are accessed in several different ways (based on fields other than id).  As such, any partitioning to them would hurt overall.  

I'm leaving out a lot of detail that doesn't effect my question, but does mean that we can't partition t1, t2, etc.

Comment: You know that no matter how many rows you delete, you won't lock the table, right?  You would only have lock contention if you were deleting a row that some other process was trying to update which seems highly unlikely.  And if someone is trying to update a row that you are trying to delete, it seems awfully reasonable for that to block.

Comment: The number of rows in the tables is irrelevant when it comes to rollback.  All that matters is the the number of rows being deleted.  Unless those rows are *huge* (say lots of clob columns) thousands of rows is a trivial amount of undo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David,
If you insist on commiting, you can use the following code:

```
declare
  type import_ids is table of integer index by pls_integer;
  my_import_ids import_ids;
  cursor c is select id from source where import_source = 'bad.txt';
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c bulk collect into my_import_ids limit 500;
    forall h in 1..my_import_ids.count
      delete from t1 where id = my_import_ids(h);
    forall h in 1..my_import_ids.count
      delete from t2 where id = my_import_ids(h);
    commit;
    exit when c%notfound;
  end loop;
  close c;
end;
```

This program fetches ids by pieces of 500 rows, deleting and commiting each piece. It should be much faster then row-by-row processing, because `bulk collect` and `forall` works as a single operation (in a single round-trip to and from database), thus minimizing the number of context switches. See [Bulk Binds, Forall, Bulk Collect](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#23723) for details.

Comment: With the commit inside the cursor I wonder whether it might be best to intorduce an ORDER BY into the cursor select in order to make sure that all values have been read from the source table prior to commiting, hopefully reducing the chances of a snapshot too old error. you'd want to check the execution plan to make sure that a sort is being performed of course.

Comment: David Aldridge: Hmm, do we need to delete rows from the "source" table as well? I overlooked it. But ORDER BY what? We'd like to sort rows so that we read them block by block, never returning to previous block again, right? I think, FULL SCAN access will do that.

Answer (score 7):

Why loop at all?

```
delete from t1 where id IN (select id from source where import_source = 'bad.txt';
delete from t2 where id IN (select id from source where import_source = 'bad.txt';
delete from source where import_source = 'bad.txt'
```

That's using standard SQL. I don't know Oracle specifically, but many DBMSes also feature multi-table JOIN-based DELETEs as well that would let you do the whole thing in a single statement.

Comment: Not possible.   Due to how large the tables are I *must* do this in a loop, commiting as I go.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle person so I can't dispute your DBA's statement, but I find it hard to believe that Oracle doesn't provide some kind of setting to commit those DELETEs as the command executes.  It's nuts that you can't issue such a simple SQL command against a major SQL database.

Comment: Hmm.  I'll ask our DBA about that.

Comment: +1 Large DELETE are not a problem, just size your rollback segments appropriately

Comment: Large deletes are a problem.  Our DBA has forbid them.  I am going to ask him about if there is a setting where it can commit each step (as Larry suggested a few comments back), but otherwise this is not possible.

Comment: A complicating factor is not only the rollback for the delete, but the rollbacks for all the inserts and updates that happen WHILE THE DELETE IS RUNNING.  Unless I hear otherwise from our DBA, one large delete is NOT an option.

Comment: Oracle does indeed support deletes against an inline view as long as it is key-preserved.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't `commit` in the loop - it is not efficient (generates lots of redo) and if some error occurrs, you can't rollback.

As mentioned in previous answers, you should issue single `delete`s, or, if you are deleting most of the records, then it could be more optimal to create new tables with remaining rows, drop old ones and rename the new ones to old names.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as select * from old_table where <filter only remaining rows>;

index new_table
grant on new table
add constraints on new_table
etc on new_table

drop table old_table
rename new_table to old_table;
```

See also [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689)

Comment: I *must* commit in a loop.  This is an order from our DBA - if I don't, the rollback information will be too large and will crash our system.
I am deleting a small minority of the records, so the create new and drop is not feasible.

Comment: Committing in loop can give you ORA-01555 errors, not mentioning poorer performance. Your DBA should rather increase rollback segment size.

Comment: Not feasible.  I expect this delete to take hours to run.  We can't have tables on our production database locked for that long.

Comment: With constraints you mentioned, I think you will be best off with egorius's solution then. It does what you want while minimizing number of context switches. I would recommend testing for the maximum amount of operations between commits - if you have so many rows to delete, it should give measurable performance boost (less redo = less writes to disk for redo log, among other things).

Answer (score 1):

Larry Lustig is right that you don't need a loop. Nonetheless there may be some benefit in doing the delete in smaller chunks. Here PL/SQL bulk binds can improve speed greatly:

```
declare
type import_ids is table of integer index by pls_integer;
my_count integer := 0;
begin
select id bulk collect into my_import_ids from source where import_source = 'bad.txt'

forall h in 1..my_import_ids.count
  delete from t1 where id = my_import_ids(h);
forall h in 1..my_import_ids.count
  delete from t2 where id = my_import_ids(h);
```

The way I wrote it it does it all at once, in which case yeah the single SQL is better. But you can change your loop conditions to break it into chunks. The key points are

- don't commit on every row. If anything, commit only every N rows.
- When using chunks of N, don't run the delete in an ordinary loop. Use `forall` to run the delete as a bulk bind, which is much faster.

The reason, aside from the overhead of commits, is that each time you execute an SQL statement inside PL/SQL code it essentially does a context switch. Bulk binds avoid that.

Comment: 2nd point: can you provide more details how forall works?  How can your query be re-written to use forall, but still commit in batches

Answer (score 0):

You may try partitioning anyway to use parallel execution, not just to drop one partition. [The Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96520/tuningpe.htm) may prove useful in setting this up. Each partition would use it's own rollback segment in this case.

Comment: Partitioning the t1, t2, etc tables is not an option due to considerations outside my control.

Comment: Well, then I answer like this:
1. Both your solutions are optimal for your circumstances.
2. You can determine which is better by testing. Do both in a simulated environment and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the delete from the source before the t1/t2 deletes, that suggests you don't have referential integrity constraints (as otherwise you'd get errors saying child records exist).

I'd go for creating the constraint with ON DELETE CASCADE. Then a simple

```
DECLARE
  v_cnt NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
  WHILE v_cnt > 0 LOOP
   DELETE FROM source WHERE import_source = 'bad.txt' and rownum < 5000;
   v_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The child records would get deleted automatically.

If you can't have the ON DELETE CASCADE, I'd go with a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS

```
DECLARE
  v_cnt NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
  WHILE v_cnt > 0 LOOP
   INSERT INTO temp (id)
   SELECT id FROM source WHERE import_source = 'bad.txt' and rownum < 5000;
   v_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
   DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
   DELETE FROM t2 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
   DELETE FROM source WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
   COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I'd also go for the largest chunk your DBA will allow.
I'd expect each transaction to last for at least a minute. More frequent commits would be a waste.

> This is happening on a system that
>   can't afford to have the tables locked
>   for that long.

Oracle doesn't lock tables, only rows. I'm assuming no-one will be locking the rows you are deleting (or at least not for long). So locking is not an issue.